# Django, Assign specific fuction tomodel field and then call it

Tags: python, django, function, model

I have a model built like this

```
class ApiPartner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('API key'), null=True)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Secret key'), null=True)
    client_key = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Client key'), null=True)
    endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Endpoint'), null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/', null=True)
```

evey API partner has its own method to retrieve data, for example

```
def get_youtube_posts(endpoint,api_key):
    results=list(requests.get(endpoint+'?key='+api_key).json())
    return results[0:50]

def get_instagram_posts(endpoint,api_key,secret_key):
    return requests.get(endpoint+'?key='+api_key+'&secret='+secret_key)
```

the question is: how do i assign the 'get_posts' function to the model so i can call a generic `ApiPartner.get_posts()` and it will retrieve the posts using the given function?
I'm thinking about like a models.FunctionField but i know that doesn't exist.
I think this is more a logical problem than a technical one but i can't find a way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm understanding the question wrong; but you can just assign it as a property on the model class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   fields...
   
   @property
   def youtube_posts(self):
       results=list(requests.get(self.endpoint+'?key='+self.api_key).json())
       return results[0:50]

   @property
   def instagram_posts(self):
       return requests.get(self.endpoint+'?key='+self.api_key+'&secret='+self.secret_key)
```

Then you can call it with the instance of your model.

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.all().first()
youtube_posts = mymodel.youtube_posts
# or
instagram_posts = mymodel.instagram_posts
```

But this will only return one or the other since your models are based on one specific endpoint.
To create a more generic method on the model, use the above methods, plus this:

```
@property
def platform_posts(self)
    if "instagram" in self.endpoint:
        return self.instagram_posts
    elif "youtube" in self.endpoint:
        return self.youtube_posts
    ... You get the gist.
```